# Transfer alerts or notifications to next route with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, notifications, url-routing, crud

I am building a CRUD (*Create, Read, Update, Delete*) form with Angular 5 and want to navigate to the route showing an overview of all already added elements including the new one.

```
this.myElement.create({
    //... Do some API magic
}).subscribe(() =>
    this.router.navigate(['/overview']);
);
```

After updating the database the user gets `router.navigate`'d to the overview. There should be displayed a message (*alert, notification, toast or what ever*) whether the change was successfull or not.

**Possible aproaches:**

1. Do I have to implement an own service to transfer informations like this one?
2. Is there a built-in solution in Angular?
3. Should I use something like an event handler or oberserver watching for any CRUD methods?

Comment: Specifing the question with more details will be appriciated.

Comment: You could go with a shared services that holds the information. Or try and redux based approach like `@ngrx/plattform`

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful where you implement this alert. If it's a service, you might do

```
.subscribe(() =>
    this.toast.show('Task is finished');
    this.router.navigate(['/overview']);
);
```

Since you are switching routes, the `toast` component has to be in the parent templates of `<router>` or up.

If the service is designed targeting the `body` tag, ex. using `position: fixed`. Then you are safe no matter what.

I don't think the entire page will get refreshed if that's your concern.

Just to answer your question

- Do I have to implement an own service to transfer informations like this one?
  **YES**, not necessarily you, but someone.
- Is there a built-in solution in Angular? **Maybe**, because you can just put an element that positioned to the screen as a simple alert. Angular doesn't do anything specific for this task.
- Should I use something like an event handler or oberserver watching for any CRUD methods? **No need**, you want to finish this alert before moving to others. However if you want others to know an alert has been fired, then YES, you want that service to publish an observerable.